# Linksys SPA-3102 password reset

Tags: voip, cisco-router

I've got a Linksys 3102 voice gateway router from a street market very cheap, but it has admin password.

I've tried the combination `***`-> `73738#` using a phone connected to the FXS port as pointed out in the [manual](https://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/ATA_AG_v3_200809_AdminGuide.pdf#page238) on page 236, but the IVR keeps asking me for a password.

Is there any way to do a hard reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to use a password that was shared in a comment from **Pete Kaloudis** on this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEQKy1O9brs)

> The password if prompted in the IVR is 41046040033